# Continuum Anaconda Fedora 22 path

Tags: linux, bash, python, path, datascience-anaconda

After an update to Windows 10 caused problems in my dual boot system I had to reinstall Fedora 22.  So, starting with a fresh system I reinstalled my work environment.  The one installation that has been troublesome is Continuum Anaconda Python.  I followed the defaults, which meant it was installed my Fedora /root directory.  No matter what I do I cannot launch any parts of the Anaconda package -- even if as root I cd into /root.  Here is my .bashrc (also in the /root directory):

```
# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
. /etc/bashrc
fi

# Enable tab completion
source home/brian/git-completion.bash

# colors!
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"

# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/root/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

If I enter "ipython" at the console prompt I get

```
bash: ipython: command not found...
Similar command is: 'python'
```

Which is why I thought it was probably a path issue.  Should I adjust my PATH?  I've tried everything I can think of.  Should I reinstall Anaconda in another location?

Comment: BrianM, now that you've added the relevant information, I'm happy to migrate it to unix.SE. However, I've edited our your "answer" part of your question, since that should be posted as an answer itself. Feel free to repost it as an answer, now the question has been migrated & re-opened.

Comment: Why are you running as root for development use? That's usually a Bad Idea on a Linux system. Since you are running as root, I assume you installed Anaconda as root, which for most installers would make the installer use someplace global like `/usr/local/anaconda/bin` for installation. Can you confirm that there really is a `/root/anaconda/bin/ipython` file at all?